# How do I make it so SonarQube comments on my pull requests on VSTS?

Tags: request, sonarqube, azure-devops, pull

I use VSTS with SonarQube extension and I am trying to do a very basic pull request from 1 branch to another. I change 1 line of code to add if(true=true) to get a reaction from sonarqube and tell me it's bad coding, however I don't see anything from the sonarqube extension when looking at the pull request. Right now My build definition for the project does not work but I think it isn't necessary for what I'm trying to do...
How can I make it so I do see sonarqube comments on my pull request?

Comment: Do you try it with a build required branch policy?

Answer (score 0):

The build definition working is absolutely required. The SonarQube extension will only publish results to a pull request when the build is running as part of a branch policy.